# Loading socket.io into JavaScriptCore for iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, socket.io, javascriptcore

I'm writing an iOS/JavaScriptCore app that calls code from a Javascript file. My Javascript code depends on the 'io' variable created by importing socket.io.js. The Javascript all works fine when loaded from an HTML file, but when I load socket.io.js into JavaScriptCore the io variable is not defined and my own Javascript can't run.

My JSCore code looks like this...

```
NSString *socketPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"socket.io" ofType:@"js"];
NSString *socketJS = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:socketPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
JSValue  *socketEval = [context evaluateScript: socketJS];

NSString *arPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"arFunctions" ofType:@"js"];
NSString *arJS = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:arPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
JSValue  *arEval = [context evaluateScript: arJS];

JSValue *function = context[@"connectToServer"];
JSValue *result = [function callWithArguments:nil];
```

The exception handler defined for the context returns these errors when evaluateScript runs on the imported socket.io file...

    `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.prototype')
    runInContext
    webpack_require
    webpack_require
    webpack_require
    webpackUniversalModuleDefinition`

The connectToServer function fails because it expects the io variable to have been defined. anyone know why the io variable is not created in the context when I call evaluateScript on socket.io.js? It looks like socket.io is missing expected definitions or other resources when runInContext and webpackUniversalModuleDefinition is evaluated, but I'm loading the exact same Javascript files in the same order as in my HTML file. What am I missing here?

I'm developing on Xcode 9 on macOS High Sierra for iOS 11.

Thanks!

Comment: is it a browser environment that offers window.WebSocket()?

Comment: It is not running in a browser. It is an ARkit iOS application.

Comment: I think the JavaScriptCore environment is missing all of the browser APIs related that SocketIO uses to establish its web sockets connections etc. Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across possibly the same issue when migrating working JavaScriptCore code to High Sierra.

In my case the issue came from my unwitting reliance on `-[NSFileManager enumeratorAtURL: includingPropertiesForKeys: options: errorHandler:]` returning an enumerator that had sorted its contents based on the path of the urls. This used to be the case in macOS 10.12, but doesn't seem to be the case in 10.13, where the ordering seems to be decided by some unknown filesystem property.